# Laravel Model has many models of different types (a collection of models)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have `Book`, `Magazine` and `Song` models.

I want to make a `Collection` model that will contain models of these three types, so I could query it like this (pseudo code):

```
Collection->get()
```

and get a result similar to this:

```
[
  {Book_1}
  {Magazine_1}
  {Book_2}
  {Song_1}
  {Book_3}
  ...
]
```

Is it possible to do in Laravel, and how would I approach this problem?

I looked at polymorphic relations, but, as I understand it, it's only possible to get one type of relationship at a time (books(), magazines(), songs()) and not a mix of them.

Answer (score 0):

A `collection` is already a "thing" (like a keyword) in Laravel, it's a wrapper class for arrays. Perhaps you could use something like "Media". If all tables have the same columns you could use [`union`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#unions) Or create 3 queries and  [`concat`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-concat) the results.

```
$books = Book::all();
$songs = Song::all();
$magazines = Magazine::all();

$media = collect([$books, $songs, $magazines]);
```